# Differentiability of a function at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that the function $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$ that is defined to be $0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. I was able to prove that all partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$ and are equal to $0$ but are not continuous at $(0,0)$. Now I need to prove that $f$ is still differentiable at $(0,0)$. Our definition of differentiability is that $lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(h_1,h_2)=L_0h+o(\|h\|)$ where $L_0$ is a linear transformation, but I don't know how to approach this, as I am new to those definitions.

Comment: Explicitly consider $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}$$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 This obviously goes to $0$, but is this the same as I wrote?

Comment: Yes. The linear transformation $L_0$ in this case is just the identically zero map.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 So the fact that the requested limit as itself goes to $0$ is enough to say that $f$ is differentiable because we can say $L_0$ is identically zero?  Which makes sense because if we assumed $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ the Jacobian matrix is exactly a $2\times1$ matrix with only $0$'s